# Identify PID of long running process

Tags: linux, shell

I need to identify long running process and save pid of that process to a file. With the below command I am able to identify age of long running process. But after this I am struck with how to grep PID of that long running process? Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
ps -eo pid,etime,cmd | grep DSD.RUN | awk '{print $2}' | ./script.sh | \
xargs -I [] bash -c 'if [ "[]" -gt "86400" ]; then echo []; fi'
```

Script.sh: (got this from stackoverflow post)

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F $':' -f <(cat - <<-'EOF'
{
    if (NF == 2) {
        print $1*60 + $2
    } else if (NF == 3) {
        split($1, a, "-");
        if (a[2] > 0) {
            print ((a[1]*24+a[2])*60 + $2) * 60 + $3;
        } else {
            print ($1*60 + $2) * 60 + $3;
        }
    }
}
EOF
) < /dev/stdin
```

Answer (score 1):

after `awk '{print $2}'`, you lose everything but the time, after that you can't get the pid easily anymore.

Instead of using an awk script to convert the time to seconds, you should just use `etimes`, and if you're already using awk, then you can just do everything in an one line awk script:

```
ps -eo pid,etimes,cmd | awk '/DSD\.RUN/ {if ($2 > 86400) {print $1}}'
```

The regular expression `/DSD\.RUN/` makes the following action apply only to lines containing `DST.RUN`.